# Add/remove class takes three seconds on ipod touch

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have a form with various inputs. Some of these inputs are initially hidden as they have a parent div with `display:None`.

I then remove the hidden class via jQuery. On my computer, the previously hidden div appears instantaneously. On the iPod Touch it takes a full three seconds. It has about 100 checkmark inputs as well as CSS formatting. The inputs are also attached to various event listeners. It's just as slow to hide the division again (code not shown for this.)

Any suggestions?

css:

```
.hidden: {display:None}
```

html (simplified):

```
<div id = "expand"></div>
<div class = "hidden" id = "city_div">
   some city <input type="checkbox">
   ...
</div>
```

script:

```
$("[id = expand]").live('click', function() {
    $("[id = city_div]").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Edit: I originally wrote iPhone, but it's an iPod Touch. Corrected it.

Comment: Any reason why you use the deprecated `live` ?

Comment: Copy paste from some original example that I saw somewhere and then never thought about it again.

Comment: Hey, I think that changing it to .click really makes it faster. I'll get back when I've tested more to see if that is what's making the difference.

Comment: Using `.click` is the same as using `.on` like I recommended in my answer. `live` is costly and deprecated, you should remove all its occurrences from your code. I see also you didn't specify the version of jQuery you use. It's an important detail speaking of performance.

Comment: Sounds like you have many elements with same ID. That's bad, use class instead.

Comment: ok, they used to all be name. Changing it to id made a big difference on the ipod. I'll see about using class

Comment: If you have more than one tag with the same `id`, the HTML will be invalid. These are meant to be unique.

Comment: @user984003 Do you really have more than one element with a given ID ? That will lead to bugs and that prevent optimizations.

Comment: Alright, it's faster now: about a second instead of three. Not awesome, but acceptable. The biggest difference was using .click instead of live. I had already changed name to id, which had previously made a huge difference. Then I changed id to class to prevent having more than one with the same id.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$("[id = expand]").live('click', function() {
    $("[id = city_div]").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

with

```
$("#expand").live('click', function() {
    $("#city_div").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

It should be much faster. Your selector was looking for all elements instead of letting jQuery simply call `document.getElementById`.

And if the #expand element exists when you bind the handler, use

```
$("#expand").on('click', function() {
    $("#city_div").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

And by the way, be sure to use a recent version of jQuery.

---

EDIT : if you have, as it seems, more than one element with a give id, **change that !** It's invalid, leads to bugs and prevents optimizations. Use classes and `$('.classname')` as it lets jQuery use the native and fast `getElementsByClassName` function.

Comment: Just tried and it's the same. Using 'id' instead of 'name' made a huge difference for me elsewhere, but I think that 'id=' is the same as '#'.

Comment: No, that's not the same. But it's hard to find **where** the time is spent without a fiddle.

Comment: @codefreak No ! Don't prefix a div selector with a tag : it prevents optimization and it makes no sense.

Comment: ok! I didn't know that. I thought being more specific in selectors may  result in faster traversing

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if accessing the hidden parent thusly would result in an improved performance?

```
$(".your-new-class").live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("hidden");
});
```

This assumes that the hidden items are immediate parents of the clickable children.

Comment: Bah, I've reread the question, and I think you are unhiding a fixed element, rather than a relative one. Ah well `:)`